# fatal error: syncstream: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, gcc

How do I install syncstream header?

```
gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 9.2.1-9ubuntu2) 9.2.1 20191008
```

Comment: You need to upgrade to at least g++ 11. Probably 11.1. Then including `syncstream` and compiling with `g++ -std=c++20 ...` works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was given by [Ted Lyngmo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7582247/ted-lyngmo) in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66203371/fatal-error-syncstream-no-such-file-or-directory/69678402#comment120812773_66203371). To have a regular answer I copied it here:

> You need to upgrade to at least g++ 11. Probably 11.1. Then including `syncstream` and compiling with `g++ -std=c++20 ...` works.`